# Symfony autowiring a service which has a string argument

Tags: symfony, service, autowired, symfony-3.3

In the documentation of [manually wiring argument](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments), The service need an explicity configuration in order to set the argument `$adminEmail`

But why dont use a default value for `$adminEmail` in the class?

```
class SiteUpdateManager
{
    private $messageGenerator;
private $mailer;
private $adminEmail;

public function __construct(MessageGenerator $messageGenerator, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, $adminEmail = 'admin@example.com')
{
    $this->messageGenerator = $messageGenerator;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->adminEmail = $adminEmail;
}
```

with setting a default value in the construct method, we don't need to define the service in services.yml file

Comment: There is no reason to add a default value for an argument on your service constructor, you can instead define the default value on the service property, in your case private $adminEmail = '....';

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't want to override the definition of the service in the YAML file in order to set only property